# how to apply jquery function only to large screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've this code it works perfect but I want to apply this only for large screen not mobile. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```html
<script>

(function($) {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();
    });
    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {
      location.href = this.href;
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
  //Add your code for large screen
}
else {
  //Add code for small screen
}
```

**EDIT**: To apply this to your code (using resize as suggested by @soloughlin3)

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).on('resize',myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
        $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
          $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
        }, function() {
          $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();
        });
        $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {
          location.href = this.href;
        });
    }        
}
```

Comment: You could also use this with the jquery resize function, so that when the browser size is changed you site will react to this. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Thanks for your and. How would you wrap this could around jQuery and what would you add for the else?

Comment: I have edited by answer to show how this would be applied including the resize suggested by @soloughlin3 .